# MultiMap Table with Guava

Tags: java, guava

Recently I have discovered Guava in all its wonder. I have come across an instance where I would like to use a combination of Multimap and Table, basically a Multimap with two keys.

Is there a Guava class to do this or should I just go with `Tabe<R, C, Map<T>>`?

Comment: Did you mean a `Table<R, C, List<T>>`? If you did then yes you have to do it manually like that (can't find the declined feature request right now.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=902

Answer (score 11):

As given by one of the project members, Louis Wasserman:

> "Conceptual consistency" is not nearly as relevant to us as the metric
>   of "utility times ubiquity."  We can't put in the kind of investment
>   that Multitable would require for the sake of a comparatively tiny
>   number of users.  For the same reason, we don't include a "three-keyed
>   map," either.
>
> That said, markaf, I can think of another solution for your specific
>   case: use a normal Multimap, but combine the first two fields into a
>   composite key.  It doesn't sound like you need to view the rows or the
>   columns of that table, you just want to look up on multiple keys at
>   once.
>
> *[And further explains in a second post]* Additionally, the composite-key approach generalizes to arbitrary numbers of fields, in contrast to your proposed Multitable interface, which only get you one extra field.

The complete discussion can be found on the [Guava Library issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=902).